# Chef resource skipped even though not_if command exits 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra

The resource has a not_if guard, and I've verified that the exit code from the command is non-zero. Yet the output of the chef run shows that the resource is skipped due to not_if.

The resource looks like

```
device_id = "/dev/xvdf"
execute 'yes | mkfs -t ext4 #{device_id}' do
    not_if 'blkid -o value -s TYPE #{device_id} && blkid -o value -s TYPE #{device_id} | grep ext4'
    timeout 1200
end
```

Comment: best guess is that the output of that command is not the same in the context in which chef runs it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sigh. Ruby doesn't interpolate in single-quote strings. Changed them to double quote and fixed the issue.

Comment: Can you accept this answer to "close" the question?

Comment: You could also try using the `%Q[ ]` format.  Everything in the brackets is treated as if it was in a double quote.